# Can jumping to a new SSID be a solution for flood attacks?

Tags: wifi, denial-of-service, flooding

If an attacker can access inside my network in any way and make a UDP or ICMP flood attack on any point of the network (server, client or router), can I prevent this attack transiently with jumping on another available ssid on the same router?

I'm asking because flood attack occurs on the network and transport layers but this solution runs on the link layer.

[image: my network]

Comment: I'm confused. Who is jumping? Won't all nodes need to jump, including the attacker?

Comment: I am jumping actually between another ssid on same router. Imagine that router has more than working network namely wifi1,wifi2,wifi3 and so on

Comment: And you are assuming that the attacker cannot also change to the other SSID?

Comment: Attacker can not know next ssid that I will connect to. So to make an another attack, he must pass over these steps : 
1. He needs to detect which ssid I am connected to (It can be same router with different network or can be on another router) 
2. To crack the password of new ssid. There is only one guy that knows all passwords and that guy is me. Without authentication, they can only make de-auth attack and to prevent this I am using 802.11x
3. Make another flood. 
I guess, to pass over these steps gain me a lot of time to handle the situation ?

Comment: OK, this is not "channel shifting". This is, "switch networks"

Comment: OK. does this method solve my problem?

Comment: It looks like you already have your answer. So, can you explain what network level threats you are expecting if you change networks?

Comment: I am asking to not missing any points actually. I am expecting to prevent layer 3 and 4 threats (udp flood, icmp flood etc) but not sure changing the network solve these type of attacks

Comment: You need access to the network in order to send network traffic

Comment: what @schroeder meant to say is "yes".
But the issue is that changing network will yield a four way handshake if it's WPA/2 Personal.